# Create Pie Chart using MVC 5 and Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, pie-chart

Has anyone had any success creating a pie chart with the MVC 5 framework that is free or very inexpensive?

**Edited:**
This is the code I'm trying to use in the View and it returns nothing.

```
@{
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    var dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables["Request"]);
    var myChart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 600, height:400)
        .AddTitle("Status Summary")
        .AddSeries(chartType: "Pie", name:"Requests", xValue: dataView, xField: "AnalystID", yValues: dataView, yFields: "RequestID")
        .Write();
}
```

This is my Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DBMR.Models
{
    public class RequestStatusCount
    {
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
        public int StatusCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult TestChart()
    {
        var items = db.Requests
        .Where(r => r.RequestID > 0)
        .GroupBy(r => new { r.Status.Name, r.StatusID })
        .Select(r => new RequestStatusCount
        {
            StatusName = r.Key.Name,
            StatusCount = r.Count()
        }).OrderByDescending(r => r.StatusCount);

        return View(items);
    }
```

Comment: There are tons of ways to do that, and you should at least specify some more technical details. Since you have mentioned ASP.NET, do you want to render the chart on the server-side as a static image? Or do you want it to be dynamically drawn on the client-side with some funky JavaScript library? Or would you like to use pure JavaScript? [Here](https://live.zoomdata.com/zoomdata/visualization?__target=embedded&key=52265abb6abdbcaa8c217789#51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346db-51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346d5) you can find a good example of dynamic pie chart built with D3.js library.

Comment: I added some context in my original post.

Comment: Before Posting any question, read the Tour of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

MVC has chart helper that you can get using [System.Web.Helpers.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers(v=vs.111).aspx) if you're not doing some fancy highly interactive chart.

For other HTML5 and JS/Jquery based Free/Open-Source library checkout

- [Google chart library](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
- [Jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php)

**Update:**
you need to provide array instead of just throwing dataView as the datasource,

In your scenario,

xValue = array of AnalystID

yValue = array of RequestID

Comment: I added a little context in my original post

Answer (score 0):

See my Simple solution, though using column as chart type

```
public ActionResult DrawChart()
        {
            var report = Db.Candidateresults.GroupBy(i => i.subject)
                            .Select(g => new {
                             Subjects = g.Key,
                             TotalScore = g.Sum(i=>i.score)
                            });

            var chart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 400, theme:ChartTheme.Green);
            foreach(var item in report)
            {

                chart.AddTitle("Statistical Performance Report")

                .AddSeries(
                 chartType: "column",            
                 xValue: new[] {item.Subjects },
                 yValues: new[] {item.TotalScore }

                ).GetBytes("png");

            }

            return File("chart", "image/bytes");
```

}